# Only able to load 1 row of new data from array into sql/WordPress table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, insert

I've seen a lot of posts on adding multiple rows of data (from an array) to a mysql table. I've looked at many of these and have tried some of the suggestions but nothing has worked to date. I have a problem I've seen others mention - only the first insert is entered in my table (in WordPress) to record user reviews of conference sessions.

In overview, I'm gathering data from a form which lists about 25 sessions in a conference program. I'm asking users to rate which one they prefer to see broadcast on the Internet. I'm able to get this data via $_POST and load it into an array. The array seems to be created successfully but I only get 1 line new data added to my virt_proposal_ratings table when I try to insert it using the foreach routine below. Here is the key code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i != $lrow; $i+=1) {
 for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x+=1) {
    echo "<p>column: " . $fcol_array["$x"] . "</p>";
    $vthscol = $fcol_array["$x"];

    $vratename = "rate_proposal" . $vthscol . $i;
    $vpropidvar = "f_propid" . $vthscol . $i;   
    $vrating = $_POST[$vratename];

    $vprop_id = $_POST[$vpropidvar];
    $vdayrowcol = $vconfday . $vthscol . $i;


   if ($vrating) {  
    echo "<p>vrating: " . $vrating . "</p>";
    if ($rc == 0) {
         $newratings[] = array('review_id'=>$vreview_id, 
                 'user_id'=>$vrater_user_id, 
             'prop_id'=>$vprop_id, 'virt_rating'=>$vrating, 'dayrowcol'=>$vdayrowcol);
    }
    else {
        array_push($newratings, $vreview_id, $vrater_user_id, $vprop_id, 
                $vrating, $vdayrowcol);
        $rc = $rc + 1;

    }
}


     foreach ( $newratings as $newrec ) { 
 $wpdb->insert('virt_proposal_ratings', 
     $newrec, array("%d", "%d", "%d", "%s"));

}
```

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure why but the above code is now working. I deleted the data table and started over. I'm wondering if the indexing might have been interfering.

Comment: I'll bet you're right -- duplicate keys were interfering with inserts?